# how to input string in console and display in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How to input a string in console and display it in a window using tkinter in python?
i want to store a string input from the console,not the entry widget and want to display it in the window created using tkinter
thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':

    txt = input('enter text: ')

    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(root, text=txt)
    label.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```